# Android alarm service

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am writing an alarm back ground service which one is best way to use a BroadCast reciever or Service.

Comment: It depends on your purpose, if you elaborate, we might be able to help instead of shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Use BR. If task you want to execute is short (5s) you can do all you want in your BR otherwise you MUST use service due to android time limit for BR execution. Refer to documentation and check what the limit is (I don't remember it exactly).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually when alarm fires I need to display dialog which takes user input.K then I will go for Service.

Comment: It's impossible to display dialog from service - use BR to recieve intent and then start activity. Probably powerlocks will be needed.